# Execute a shell command in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, shell

i'm doing a web page in javascript and i need to execute a windows shell script when i click on a button. When i looked it up on the internet, all the "solutions" were to use nodeJS. But i'm not sure if i'll work because i need something (if it's possible) that could be in the `<script>` part of my HTML file or something that i won't need to start like a server side.

Thanks,

GameBoyDev45

PS: The cmd i'm trying to launch is `start [Path to the file]`

Comment: Well, that would be a massive security problem if it was possible.

Comment: This is not possible. Imagine someone creating a webpage which when loaded would run a shell script to steal the info stored in env.